# Python Lists Beginner

Tags: python, django, list

I created a list in Python:

```
mylist=os.listdir("/User/Me/Folder")
```

now I have a list of files in a List.

What I would like to do is:

Take one file name after the other and add a URL to it:

/myurl/ + each item in mylist

And then I would like to write the result in a html template from Django.

So that it display all the images in that folder in a list of html

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using list comprehensions, you can transform your original list, "mylist", into a list with the URL prefix like so:

```
urllist = ['/myurl/%s' % the_file for the_file in mylist]
```

Analysis:

a) the expression in the square brackets is the list comprehension. it says: iterate over each item in "mylist", temporarily calling the iterated item "the_file" and transform it using the subexpression: '/myurl/%s' % the_file

b) the transformation expression says, create a string where %s is replaced by the string represented by the value of "the_file"

Comment: cool thanks a million for the explanation. And the_file has to be called the the_file or can be called any name or has to do with mylist?

Comment: @MacPython It can be called anything, but it has to be consistent: For example ` '/myurl/%s' % a_shoe for a_shoe in mylist`

Comment: I am so close I can smell it. 

in the {% for url in urllist %} I wrote

<p><img src='{{ urllist }}' alt="cogbio"/></p>

But now it writes the list in the variable.
But I want to write 1 file after the other, as a list of images.

How can I achieve this

Thanks so much!!

Comment: I also have another problem in the list he writes me:

[&#39;/site_media/Gallery/Image,...]
So for every link he adds &#39.

Any idea why that can be?

Comment: Yeah ! Rooibos you just made my week. I now understand what Ignacio wrote in other words. For everybody who will get this wrong in the future:

In the template write:

{% for url in urllist %}

{{ url }} !!!!!

And not

{{ urllist }}

Thanks so much for that. You cant understand how much that helped me. 
So simple.

Answer (score 3):

```
{% for filename in listoffilenames %}
  /myurl/{{ filename }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that does not work for me. I writes in the html:

/myurl/[item1,...., item20]
.
.
/myurl/[item1,...., item20]

As many times as there is items in the list I guess.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You put the list in the loop instead of the iterator variable.

Comment: Sorry but what would be the iterator variable?

Comment: In the example I give it's `filename`.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. In the views.py I have:

def mydef(request):
     allimg= os.listdir("/Users/Me/Folder")
     allimg[:] = ["/site_media/Gallery/"+ x for x in allimg]
     return render_to_response('mytemplate.html',
                                     {'allimg': allimg})

In my template: 

{% for i in allimg %}
  /site_media/Gallery/{{ allimg }}
{% endfor %}

And I get the same as before but now with /site_media/Gallery/[item 1-item n]

Comment: Why are you printing `allimg` if the iterator variable is `i`? And why are you doing it in *both* the view *and* the template?

Answer (score 1):

For contrast, if you feel like doing this in the view (even though there's no good reason to do so):

```
mylist[:] = [url + x for x in mylist]
```

If you don't need to modify the existing list then you can drop the `[:]`.

Comment: I didn't know the x[:] = y idiom. Thanks! (Might be confusing for a beginner though)